# 'police' and 'police officers' in American English

Tags: american-english, collective-nouns

I'm wondering whether 'police' and 'police officers' are interchangeable in the following in American English:

1. Twelve police officers / police were killed in the shoot-out.
2. More than 20 police officers / police were called to the crime scene.
3. Several police officers / police were killed in the shoot-out.

The noun 'staff' cannot have the number specified as in 'the company has 
20 staff' in American English. I'm not sure that's also true of 'police'.

Comment: you can say 20 staff members or 20 members of the staff. But police can be a count noun.

Comment: Yes, "police" and "police officers" are interchangeable in those sentences. But in my idiolect "police officers" is much more common in such sentences. I think a good answer to this question will cite frequency data comparing these constructions.

Comment: Generally, "policemen" would be a closer equivalent to "police officers".  "Police" tends to be used to refer to the organization vs individuals in it.

Comment: "Police Officers" is the preferred modern American English term, as it's more gender-neutral than "Police*men".*

Comment: I am not asking about which one is the preferred form gender-wise; rather, i'm asking whether 'three police' sounds natural in American English (without a following 'officers').

Comment: An E1L speaker (of the US variety) would never say, eg, "a police arrived 5 minutes after the accident" -- it would be "policeman" or "police officer".  Oddly, however, there is a slight chance that "three police arrived..." might be said.

Comment: Here is an example use of "three police" in a headline: https://www.rt.com/usa/351706-baton-rouge-cops-shot/

Comment: @Silenus - So isn't it the case that, used as a noun, "police" is plural, while "policeman" is the closest equivalent singular?

Answer (score 3):

In AmE, police generally refers to a group of law-enforcement personnel, and police officers refers to the individuals serving in that role, although the latter varies by country: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Police_officer